# How do I put file in folder?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

```
file_put_contents('c_' . $id . '_node.json', $jsonData);
```

Currently it creates new file in root directory, but I want to put this file content in particular folder.

Comment: `file_put_contents('particular folder/c_' . $id . '_node.json', $jsonData);`

Comment: Did you try with `file_put_contents('/my/path/to/the/folder/c_' . $id . '_node.json', $jsonData);` ?

Comment: just give full path in first parameter.

Comment: Did you look in the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php **filename
Path to the file where to write the data.**

Comment: Not getting this, it generates in project root folder, and i want this like file_put_contents('json_data/c_' . $id . '_node.json', $jsonData);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the folder exists, just add it to the first parameter

```
file_put_contents('PATH/TO/FOLDER_NAME/c_' . $id . '_node.json', $jsonData);
```

Comment: Not getting this, it generates in project root folder, and i want this like
file_put_contents('json_data/c_' . $id . '_node.json', $jsonData);